# list item ignoring set height, using wrap_content instead

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a problem with my list item layouts that i cannot understand. I set the height of a list item to 70dp but if i only have content with a total height of 40dp it will automatcally just ignore the value i set with android:layout_height and instead use what seems to be wrap_content as the height.

If i use the exakt same layout outside of a list it works as intended.

below is the layout of a list item from one of my lists.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="70dip"
android:layout_width="fill_parent">

<TextView android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@style/NormalText"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@style/VerySmallLightText"/></LinearLayout>
```

Editted my xml to reflect my code better. i have some of there attributes in style, that is why i accidently made a typo when tying it in manually here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried layout_height of the linear layout instead of just the height?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="70dp"*
android:layout_width="fill_parent">
```

Comment: typo on my part, i ofcourse have layout_height i the code:9 changing my post to reflect this now

Answer (score 0):

your linearlayout attribute the following
   android:height = '70dip'  is it can passing the IDE checking?

Comment: updated my posted code, it was just a typo when i wrote the code here